# HTML form data not being posted to use in SQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

this should be simple but I have lost my way
simple form on HTML page - select Men, Women or Junior
then send that that value to a php page to perform SQL query and find all the Men, Women or Juniors using the variable "$trigen"
display the results on the HTML page using AJAX

if I set $trigen manually it works, but not when I choose the option in the form as set out in this code:--

my HTML:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div class="entry-content">
        

<form action="/getcustomer.php" method="POST">
  <label for="trigen">Choose a gender:</label>
  <select id="trigen" name="trigen">
    <option value="Men">Men</option>
    <option value="Women">Women</option>
    <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
  </select>


<button class="btn btn-primary text-center btn-block btn-flat" style="h2; margin: 20px; color:black;  " name="trilookup" type="submit" onclick="showResults()"> Search</button>

 
</form>

   </div>
   
<div id="results">Results go here if it works....</div>


<script>



function showResults(str) {
  
  var xhttp;
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getcustomer.php?q="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

then my php code in   "getcustomer.php"

```
<?php  


    //connect to the database
    
  $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','wetsuder_user1','user123','wetsuder_finder');
  if($conn){
      
  }
  else{
     echo  "Sorry there is a connection error".mysqli_connect_error();
  }

                 
$trigen=$_POST['trigen'];
    
 
 //this is the search
 
$sql = "SELECT id, Gender, Wetsuit FROM wp_wetsuitdata WHERE Gender = '$trigen'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    
  echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
  
  
  // output data of each row
  
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["Gender"]." ".$row["Wetsuit"]."</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I don't see big error, do you test to add mysqli->error to check if there is a sql error. Try to print your variable also. Think to add a check with is set function to be sure variable is not empty

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `button` is causing a form submission. Just add `preventDefault()` as the first line of your `showResults` function and it will prevent the form from submitting naturally. You're handling the form submission via ajax. Also you don't need to have an action or method on your `<form` tag for the same reason. Another way of preventing the form from submitting is like this: `<form onsubmit="return false"`

Also, change your function to find the value you want to send, since you're not actually passing that value through the function call `str`

```
function showResults() {
  preventDefault(); // prevents form submission
  // get the value
  let str = document.getElementById('trigen').value;
  // check to make sure it's there...
  if (!str) return alert("Please select an option...");
  var xhttp;
  ......
```

You're sending the data via GET (when you use the ?q=val on your URL, the data is being sent through GET. So, you can receive it in your PHP with this:

```
$trigen=$_GET['q'];
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look at my code.  I still can't get it working.

Comment: what isn't working exactly? at what point are you not getting the results you want?

Comment: I don't get any results at all.  does not even say 0 results.  I think there is an error as I am not defining any str in showResults(str)

Comment: Sorry, I completley missed something first time around, please see revised answer

Comment: @lostinspace - how did that work for you?

Comment: It appears that you are a genius.  It is working beautifully now thanks.  You have fixed my weekend headache.  Thank you.